# Open document from share point directly in office365

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I'm using the graph API to access the documents in SharePoint. The response I'm getting looks like this:
[graph api response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wrnW.png)

I want to let the user open this file (an excel file in this example) using excel desktop app. In other words, I want to resemble in my app the "Open in desktop app" functionality Excel for the web already provides:
[excel for the web functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHsYT.png)

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and get the webUrl of the parent folder of the document you want to open. On that webUrl you add:

```
String documentUrl = parentWebUrl + "/YourDocumentName.docx";
```

And then you use Office URI scheme to open it localy (read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-uri-schemes))

It should be possible to do it using the webUrl of the document itself, but i have not figured out how to do it.

Comment: I was wrong, there is a way. The answer is "webDavUrl". It will work correctly. Just make sure to specifically select it. (Butt you still need to use Office URI scheme)